# Looping through 3 css phases when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it so that when any letter is clicked it will go to the next 'phase'. first being opacity = 1 and black color, the second opacity = 0.2. the third it turns blue and opacity = 1. I am having trouble with it turning to blue and opacity back to 1 on google chrome and I can't even get opacity = .2 on jsfiddle. I do have the jquery color plugin in my head,

`<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.0.js"></script>`

My javascript is a little rough so I'm assuming there is something wrong there.

Here it is
https://jsfiddle.net/tombatan/jLu4kLwo/1/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.alphabetLetter').click(function () {
        if ($(this).css('opacity') == '1' && $(this).css('color') == '#414141') {
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 0.2
            }, 250);
        } else if ($(this).css('opacity') == '0.2') {
            $(this).animate({
                color: '#145ECF',
                opacity: 1
            }, 250);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                color: '#414141'
            }, 250);
        }
    });
});
```

Does anyone know whats wrong with it?

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your request. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so when you click a letter, the first click will make its opacity 0.2. If you click again it will turn blue and opacity 1.  If you click a third time it will go back to black with opacity 1.

Comment: Have a look to [@caeth's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31662712/2788131) then. It looks like he got it figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here, first of all:

```
if ($(this).css('opacity') == '1' && $(this).css('color') == '#414141') {
```

This should check for `#000000`, not for `#414141`.

Secondly, `$(this).css('color')` this returns rgb-value, not hex.

`if ($(this).css('opacity') == '0.2')`

This will not match, since `jQuery.css('opacity')` will return a float value, for example `0.20000000035`, which will not be equal to `0.2`.

Lastly you wanna change back to `#000000` in final else.

You can do it something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.alphabetLetter').click(function () {
        if ($(this).css('opacity') == '1' && $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: 0.2
            }, 250);
        } else if (Math.round(100 * parseFloat($(this).css('opacity'))) / 100 == 0.2) {
            $(this).animate({
                color: '#145ECF',
                opacity: 1
            }, 250);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                color: '#000000'
            }, 250);
        }
    });
});
```

I've updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jLu4kLwo/7/

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense, and that's a very slick trick with the opacity. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#alphabet p").addClass("stage1");

$('.alphabetLetter').click(function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target);

        if (target.hasClass("stage1")) {
            target.toggleClass("stage1 stage2")
            .animate({
                opacity: "0.2"
            }, 250);
        } else if (target.hasClass("stage2")) {
            target.toggleClass("stage2 stage3")
            .animate({
                color: '#145ECF',
                opacity: 1
            }, 250);
        } else if(target.hasClass("stage3")) {
            target.toggleClass("stage3 stage1")
            .animate({
                color: '#414141'
            }, 250);
        }
    });
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLu4kLwo/10/)

Answer (score -1):

right syntax is:
    $(this).css({'opacity':'0.2'})

Comment: The OP is doing a comparison. Here, you are setting the value which can also be written: `$(this).css('opacity', '0.2');` (if there's only one property to set).